# Изменение типа переменной Java

Tags: java, syntax

Я хочу при запуске программы через cmd сразу передать ей нужные аргументы для дальнейшей работы с ними. То есть, пишу что-то типа C:>java Main arg1 arg2

Мне нужно передать этой программе в качестве аргументов несколько целых чисел, но они принимаются как объекты типа String. Как передать аргументы, чтобы они были восприняты как числа? Можно ли в Java преобразовать строку "5" в число 5 ? В интернете нашел способ

```
a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

Но он работает только если взять args в нужном срезе. Если, например, попробовать что-то типа

```
a = Integer.parseInt("5");
```

То выходит ошибка.
Мне нужно понять это поведение и объяснить, как передать в программу при ее запуске через cmd целые числа

Также, хотелось бы узнать, наоборот - как можно преобразовать (целое) число(5) в строку("5") (Если можно)

Comment: Какая ошибка выходит? Не должно там ни какой ошибки возникать.

Comment: jvexp.java:9: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
  a = Integer.parseInt('5');
                       ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

Comment: Вы пытаетесь строковой переменной присвоить число. Измените на `int a = Integer.parseInt("5")`

Comment: Не, не. Я по привычке от Питона в программе строку "5" в одинарных кавычках написал. Ну уж извиняйте - позавчера начал учить язык, пока немного путаюсь. Вы не подскажете как обратно из числа строку сделать?

Comment: `String.valueOf(5)`

Answer (score 1):

При желании массив args можно взять в нужном срезе и соответствующее присвоить переменной числового типа:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

Таким же способом строку можно превратить в число:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("5");
```

И наоборот - число в строку:

```
String b = String.valueOf(5);

// Спасибо пользователю @Sergey_Gornostaev
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `main()` принимает в качестве аргументов массив строк. Даже если бы Java позволяла изменение типов, то вышеуказанный метод все так же будет работать со строковыми аргументами.

Comment: Ну так а если мне в программу нужно передать целые числа?

Comment: см выше про `parseInt()`